# Code::Blocks Project Dosen't Work Correctly

Tags: ide, codeblocks

I have a project that I am working on in Code::Blocks (It's for a DLL File) and It won't compile correctly.
Code::Blocks says that a file that is in the project dosen't exist.
I am running Code::Blocks 13.12.

Note : I Replaced the name of the project and file extentions with # for privacy purposes.
Note : The file ntoskrnl.h exists, and is in the project. This is what I was talking about.

Build Log :

```
-------------- Build: Release in (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

[  0.3%] mingw32-gcc.exe -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -DBUILD_DLL -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -c \Source\Kernel\cache\cachesub.c -o output\Source\Kernel\cache\cachesub.c.o
[  0.5%] mingw32-gcc.exe -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -DBUILD_DLL -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -c \Source\Kernel\cache\copysup.c -o output\Source\Kernel\cache\copysup.c.o
[  0.8%] mingw32-gcc.exe -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -DBUILD_DLL -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -c \Source\Kernel\cache\fssup.c -o output\Source\Kernel\cache\fssup.c.o
[  1.1%] mingw32-gcc.exe -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -DBUILD_DLL -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -c \Source\Kernel\cache\lazyrite.c -o output\Source\Kernel\cache\lazyrite.c.o
[  1.4%] mingw32-gcc.exe -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -DBUILD_DLL -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -c \Source\Kernel\cache\logsup.c -o output\Source\Kernel\cache\logsup.c.o
\Source\Kernel\cache\cachesub.c:12:22: fatal error: ntoskrnl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

\Source\Kernel\cache\copysup.c:11:22: fatal error: ntoskrnl.h: No such file or directory
\Source\Kernel\cache\fssup.c:12:22: fatal error: ntoskrnl.h: No such file or directory 
\Source\Kernel\cache\lazyrite.c:11:22: fatal error: ntoskrnl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

\Source\Kernel\cache\logsup.c:11:22: fatal error: ntoskrnl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Please Help!

Comment: This is not related to C# at all, why did you revert the edit?

Comment: I didn't know that that was what you edited. I normally revert moderator edits because they often annoy me on a different forum that I used to post onto.

Answer (score 1):

Check your search directories to make sure the directory all your headers are in get found.

Right click on the project and go to build options->search directories. From there you will see 3 tabs, compiler, linker, and resource compiler. Be sure to add the correct directories so that the compiler, linker, and resource compiler respectively can find the files your project needs.